# Storyboard Bug - iOS 5.1 - Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode4.3

In my iOS project (using xcode only), I continue to run into a problem where layout presented to me in the storyboard editor becomes automatically modified after some change (which I have not been able to specifically determine). The problem is as follows:
The TabBarController has for whatever reason started displaying in landscape orientation.
Some of the NavigationControllers have also done the same thing.
I can no longer see or edit the navigation bar on my nested views.
I can no longer see of edit the tab bar on the views of the resp. tab bar items.
Everything works properly when I run the app in my simulator. If I had set it up prior to this change in default display settings, it still works just fine.

Here is a screen shot of the problem:

[image: http://imgur.com/GnyvD]

My storyboard has consistently presented me with this bug throughout the course of my project. I have fixed it once by resetting via git and another time by rebuilding the entire storyboard. Both solutions worked for an extended period of time, but I would rather have a permanent solution. Any input would be helpful.

Comment: You're probably going to have better luck submitting your project along with a bug report to Apple.  Or maybe you'll get lucky and it'll be fixed in 4.4 in a few weeks.

Comment: I've filed the bug report. I'll post their response when I receive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found out what the problem was. My project went for a toss when the same thing happened.

Firstly i think i know how it happens, I placed a view controller to the storyboard and didn't connect it to any view neither did I give it an identifier. XCODE threw a warning but i had to close the project and when i re-opened, this happend.

To solve the problem, its simple. Go through every view controller (like navigation controller, tableview controller etc) and make sure both **Orientation** and **Top Bar** and set to **Inferred**. Its important all are Inferred or else this will happen.

note: This is setting is found under *Attributes Inspector* of every view

Comment: This worked. It was the view controller that was standing alone which caused the problem. Removal of this controller immediately fixed the problem. All of my other navigators and controllers were already set to inferred. Thanks carbonr